# Lighting LEDs: What does 3-Step or 5-Step MacAdam ellipse mean

Tags: led, lighting

While searching for lighting LEDs in the range of 3500K to 5000K, I see results that show 4000K or 5000K alone, and some results that show 5000K 5-Step MacAdam Ellipse (well, all four combinations of 4000K or 5000K with or without 5-Step or 3-Step MacAdam Ellipse).

What does that mean? What is the difference between LEDs that specify:

- 4000K
- 4000K 3-Step MacAdam Ellipse
- 4000K 5-Step MacAdam Ellipse

Comment: I found [a good article from Lumistrips](https://www.lumistrips.com/lumistrips-blog/macadam_elipse_white_led_sorting_exlained/) that addresses this. I don't have time to post a full answer at the moment.

Comment: We definitely have drastically different opinions on what a good explanation is (well, paraphrasing from your "a good article") ...  I mean, 5-step MacAdam ellipse means choose the card symbol and ask for 5 cards in order ... ... ... errmmm.... riiiiight .... (I _do_ understand that the cards are an analogy .... but I haven't the slightest idea of what the analogy is, or how it makes sense to compare that still-mysterious-to-me notion to a selection of cards).

Comment: The only saver in that article is that it seems to be that 3-Step is best (in terms of color consistency across different LEDs of the same model), 5-Step is satisfactory, and the ones that don't say anything (that part is not clear ... is "no sorting" supposed to correspond to the 4000K specification?) are worst in terms of color consistency.

Comment: More steps = bigger production spread in chromatic coordinates (x, y) or temperature.

Comment: Thanks @winny ‒ found [this other article](https://www.wired4signsusa.com/blogs/led-technical-blog/what-are-macadam-ellipses-and-how-they-affect-led-color-consistency) where they mention the link that was missing in my mind: essentially the quantitative version of what you mention: each step corresponds to one standard deviation, where one standard deviation corresponds to what the average human eye perceives as no difference (or in other words, what's within one standard deviation, or 1-step, is perceived by the average human as the same color)

Comment: @Cal-linux That's a good article too! Certainly cleared up some of my understanding by explaining standard deviation color matching as being the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Individual LEDs from a given manufacturing line aren't all identical. Manufacturers try to control things tightly but still need to *bin* LEDs based on chromaticity (color), brightness (flux), and electrical properties.

The human eye is good at noticing slight differences in color (and even better at noticing brightness differences, which lossy image compression algorithms take advantage of). Because of this, LEDs all purported to the same color or a given color temperature can still vary enough to cause discrepancy in the perceived color when comparing them.

A "[MacAdam ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacAdam_ellipse)" is an ellipse drawn on a chromaticity chart to show a group of colors that the average human eye will perceive as "same color." Since chromaticity diagrams are based on hue and saturation without intensity, and (most importantly) human perceptual uniformity, they have a semi-triangular shape.

[image: MacAdam ellipses on chromaticity diagram]

<sup>[CC BY-SA 3.0](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=173591)</sup>

The ellipses are so-shaped and oriented because the human eye is not equally sensitive to all wavelengths of light.

The *size* of the ellipse can be varied as well. A "one-step MacAdam ellipse" means that every point along the perimeter is one standard variance from the center color (presumably based on MacAdam's test subject perceptions).

Thus a 7-step option will have a lot more variability in color than a 5- or 3-step. The smaller the ellipse, the less variation overall.

The [article I linked in a comment](https://www.lumistrips.com/lumistrips-blog/macadam_elipse_white_led_sorting_exlained/) tries to make an analogy using playing cards to explain MacAdam ellipse binning. I agree with the comment that it is perhaps not the best analogy nor explanation. The idea is that a given suite (♥, for example) represent one of the "bins" from the manufacturer. Within the suite *(or bin, whatever)*, you can specify how much variance in terms of *consecutive* values you want to *further* control the binning. Specifying "5-step," for example, is meant to be like accepting only a 5-value range — it might be from 2♥ to 6♥, or from 9♥ to K♥, but the variation is better controlled.

I also found an arguably [better article at Leapfrog Lighting](https://leapfroglighting.com/led-lighting-macadam-ellipse/), should you be interested.

**TL;DR: Lower numbers of MacAdam ellipse steps mean tighter control over chromaticity variance and better uniformity, albeit at higher cost.**

Comment: And, by the way the ellipses are defined, 1 "step" equals a just-noticeable-difference. So if you have process control within 1 step, the average person is physiologically unable to see the difference between samples; 3 steps is 3 times as much variation, etc.